# How to plot ROC Curve Weighted by Prevalence for Multiclass Problems

Tags: python, matplotlib, roc, auc

I checked out Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) from scikit-learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html).

It worked perfectly but I was wondering if it were possible to plot ROC Curve Weighted by Prevalence (multiclass ovo or ovr).

Comment: Please show us what you already have!

Comment: Thxs Calimo! To make it as easy as possible, let's considerer the case in sckit-learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html).

They use the Iris dataset.  The example shows how to get AUC and to plot ROC . They get ROC per class and the global curves versions (micro-average and macro-average versions).

I would like to plot a macro-weighted global ROC Curve. I think we have two possible curves:

1. Macro-Weighted with OvO.
2. Macro-Weighted with OvR.

In this example, this two possible scores were calculated, but not plotted.